# многоуровневое меню телеграм бота ( inline — callback = answer) на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, бот

Проблема заключается в том, что при коде (представленном ниже), answer = 9 и 10 не отсылают ответ.
answer 11 отсылает ответ. но если добавить answer 12, то answer 9,10,11 не отсылает ответ, а только 12-й.
Проще говоря отсылается только последний answer.

```
import telebot
import emoji
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot (TOKEN)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])

def start_message(message):
    markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Свобода', callback_data=1))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Новая волна', callback_data=2))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Техно', callback_data=3))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='На офисе', callback_data=4))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Надежда', callback_data=5))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Надежда Он-лайн', callback_data=6))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Центр', callback_data=7))
    markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Волжский', callback_data=8))



    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  'Здравствуй, ' + message.from_user.first_name + '. Я помогу подобрать тебе ближайшее собрание', reply_markup=markup)

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def query_handler(call):
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Минуточку, готовлю список!')
        answer = ''
        if call.data == '1':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="9")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="10")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="11")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '2':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="12")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="13")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="14")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '3':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="15")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="16")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="17")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '4':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="18")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="19")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="20")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '5':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="21")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="22")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="23")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '6':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="24")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="25")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="26")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        elif call.data == '7':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="27")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="28")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="29")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        elif call.data == '8':
            key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            but_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Закрытое", callback_data="30")
            but_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Открытое", callback_data="31")
            but_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Рабочее", callback_data="32")
            key.add(but_1, but_2, but_3)
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип собрания', reply_markup=key)
        if call.data == '9':
            answer = '\U0001F695 адрес.\n \U0001F3EB Группа "Свобода"\n \U0001F4C5 Понедельник, Среда, Пятница.\n \U0001F554  Начало в 18.00!'
        elif call.data == '10':
            answer = 'Открытые собрания временно не проводятся'
        elif call.data == '11':
            answer = 'Рабочее собрание проводится каждую последнюю пятницу месяца'



            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, answer)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать 4 пробела (или один символ табуляции) перед `bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, answer)`.

Потому что, если этого не сделать, то эта строка будет относиться к последнему elif-блоку.